# Java: Display Error When JTextField is left Empty

Tags: java

I've done all the coding for this mid-term exam I got going on, but I've run into this one snag. Mainly, I cannot seem to get my code to throw an error message at a user when they leave one JTextField empty. I think the issue I am having here is that I've declared double variables for each of the JTextFields (with Double.parseDouble) and as far as all my searching around goes, there is no way to check for an empty double value. I've tried a strange workaround where I declare another set of String variables for the same JTextfields (i.e. they already have double variables attributed to them) and then testing for stringVariable.equals("") but that doesn't work either.

I've tried simply going straight from the JTextField  - myJTextField.getText().equals("") - and that doesn't throw my error message either.

Keep in mind I am in a beginning Java course so this should be a simple solution.

My code for the relevant section is below:

```
  // IF statement to display error message if no name entered
  // OR no value input for any week's Homework
  // OR no JCheckBox isSelected
  // remember to check against the null string or non-selection of JCheckBox

if ( ( name.equals ( "" ) ) ||

    (homework1JTextField.getText().equals(""))||

    //Test against incorrect range of values for homework grades
    (tut1 < 0 || tut1 > 10)||
    (tut2 < 0 || tut2 > 10)||
    (tut3 < 0 || tut3 > 10)||
    (tut4 < 0 || tut4 > 10)||
    (tut5 < 0 || tut5 > 10)||
    (tut6 < 0 || tut6 > 10)||
    (tut7 < 0 || tut7 > 10)||

    (!discussionBoardZeroJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardOneTwoJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardThreeFourJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardFiveSixJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardSevenJCheckBox.isSelected()
    )

   )

  {

  // display error message
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
        "Full Name, all homework points and at least one discussion board checkbox are
 all required information!",
        "Missing Information", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy test is:

```
if (homework1JTextField.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    // throw error
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for (as it is super simple and does not include incredibly advanced Java coding) but it still doesn't throw my error. I've updated my code section to include my whole document of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would say why don't you assign intermediate boolean variables for each of those groups of comparisons. Use these booleans in the if.

Print out the values of the booleans since you're if is pretty complex, there's scope for lots of things to go wrong here.

Comment: You just went about 5 miles above my head. I know a boolean rings true or false and that I have many boolean statements in my if statement that I want to verify as true to throw my error. But what do you mean by print out the values of my booleans? **Looks blankly into space**

Comment: do something like System.out.println("name.equals="+name.equals ( "" ))

Comment: You might also wan to do something like
bool =  (!discussionBoardZeroJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardOneTwoJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardThreeFourJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardFiveSixJCheckBox.isSelected() &&
     !discussionBoardSevenJCheckBox.isSelected()
    )

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to fix the problem.  Here is one.  Replace JTextField with JTextFieldWithDefault to cause an out of range value (-1) to be returned if the user does not type something or just types spaces.  Your existing code remains unchanged and will now work as you expect.

```
public class JTextFieldWithDefault extends JTextField {
    public JTextFieldWithDefault() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String getText() {
        String s = super.getText();
        return s.trim().equals("")?"-1":s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't the OP want it to be simple? He might not understanding overriding implementations of default widgets

Comment: @DheeB - This is a basic Java technique that every Java programmer must master.  There are various ways to fix his problem.  This is one.

Comment: there definitely are many ways and this is one of the ways. I'm not sure I agree on this being necessary, though.